# MongoDB - calculate average from date ranges

Tags: arrays, mongodb

In my application I store response times as arrays grouped in 5-minute intervals like so:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56ad2e080fa76101bdd17573"),
    "date" : ISODate("2016-01-30T21:40:00Z"),
    "response_times" : [
        10,
        22,
        21,
        37
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56ad2c9d0fa76101bdd17572"),
    "date" : ISODate("2016-01-30T21:35:00Z"),
    "response_times" : [
        27,
        32
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56ad29c30fa76101bdd17571"),
    "date" : ISODate("2016-01-30T21:20:00Z"),
    "response_times" : [
        7
    ]
}
```

In no one hit my application in a given interval than (obviously) that "window" is missing like in the example above - we have 21:20:00, 21:35:00 and 21:40:00.

The question here is how to query those results and get the *average* of all response times for the last month (31 results returned per query, one result for each day) and for the last day (24 results returned per query, one result for each hour)?

To visualise for example a "monthly" aggregate I would expect to get something like:

```
{
    "date": ISODate("2016-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
    "response_time": 21
},
{
    "date": ISODate("2016-01-02T00:00:00Z"),
    "response_time": 32
},
{
    "date": ISODate("2016-01-03T00:00:00Z"),
    "response_time": 43
}
```

Also, maybe the form in which I store my response times is flawed and should I change it make querying the data easier? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you have a large dataset. It would be good to store the avg times by day, week, month and so on. So you must not calculate this much. Check the mongo schema from the tracking tool count.ly they do it this way to get the results fast.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the aggregation framework for this:

```
db.so.aggregate( 
    [ { $unwind : "$response_times" }, 
      { $group: 
          { _id:"$date", 
            average: { $avg : "$response_times" } } } 
    ] )
```

It gives the following output

```
{

"result" : [
    {
        "_id" : ISODate("2016-01-30T21:35:00Z"),
        "average" : 29.5
    },
    {
        "_id" : ISODate("2016-01-30T21:40:00Z"),
        "average" : 22.5
    }
],

"ok" : 1
}
```